# How can I implement solr redundancy on the haystack side?

Tags: python, solr, django-haystack, redundancy

I've configured solr+zookeeper and now I want to set up redundancy in haystack. I mean that if haystack cannot connect to master server he should choose slave ...

settings.py:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'master': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr',
        'TIMEOUT': 10,
        'SILENTLY_FAIL': True,
        'EXCLUDED_INDEXES': [],
        'INCLUDE_SPELLING': True,
    },
    'slave': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:7574/solr',
        'TIMEOUT': 10,
        'SILENTLY_FAIL': True,
        'EXCLUDED_INDEXES': [],
        'INCLUDE_SPELLING': True
    },
}
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS['default'] = HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS['master']
HAYSTACK_ROUTERS = [
    'apps.search.routers.MasterRouter',
    'apps.search.routers.SlaveRouter',
    'haystack.routers.DefaultRouter',
]
```

I was thinking that with configuration above the system will be able to choose the correct server. I turned off "master" server and I see that haystack still try to connect to the "master". Why? Should I set something else?

**UPDATE**

So, after I was thinking a lot of this issue I updated my router.py file:

```
class MasterRouter(routers.BaseRouter):
    def for_write(self, **hints):
        return 'master'

    def for_read(self, **hints):
        if check_connection('master'):
          return 'master'
        elif check_connection('slave'):
          return 'slave'

        return None


class SlaveRouter(routers.BaseRouter):
    def for_write(self, **hints):
        return None

    def for_read(self, **hints):
        return 'slave'


def check_connection(type):
  url = settings.HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS[type]['URL']
  try:
    urllib2.urlopen(url,timeout=1)
    return True
  except urllib2.URLError as err: pass
  return False
```

Is this a good approach ?

Comment: What is in your `apps.search.routers.MasterRouter` and `apps.search.routers.SlaveRouter`?

Comment: Now I added there a special code for checking connection availability. Is it good approach?

Answer (score 0):

Well it should work. But I don't see need for redundant `haystack.routers.DefaultRouter` and `apps.search.routers.SlaveRouter` (all your logic in `MasterRouter`).

As for `check_connection()` then more straightforward version is

```
def check_connection(type):
  url = settings.HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS[type]['URL']
  try:
    urllib2.urlopen(url,timeout=1)
    return True
  except urllib2.URLError as err:
    return False
```

If you want further to improve it you can send some real query and check for results, eg.

```
def check_connection(type):
  url = "{}?{}".format(settings.HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS[type]['URL'], 'q=test')
  try:
    res = urllib2.urlopen(url, timeout=1)
    # TODO: parse Solr output and decide what to return 
    return True
  except urllib2.URLError as err:
    return False
```

Refere to [Solr docs](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) for help on queries and output.